# Rake delete files task

Tags: ruby, msbuild, rake

In msbuild I can delete part of files in certain directory like this

```
<ItemGroup>
     <FilesToDelete Include="$(DeploymentDir)\**\*" exclude="$(DeploymentDir)\**\*.log"/>
</ItemGroup>
<Delete Files="@(FilesToDelete)" />
```

It will delete all files except *.txt

Is there some rake task I can similar thing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ruby has built in classes to make this easy:

```
Dir['deployment_dir/**/*'].delete_if { |f| f.end_with?('.txt') }
```

However, for some built in tasks, rake has helpers for this.  Adapted from the [API docs](http://rake.rubyforge.org/) you can select files like so:

```
files_to_delete = FileList.new('deployment_dir/**/*') do |fl|
  fl.exclude('*.txt')
end
```

Then you can feed this into your delete task.

Better yet, you can use the built in CLEAN/CLOBBER tasks:

```
# Your rake file:
require 'rake/clean'

# [] is alias for .new(), and we can chain .exclude
CLEAN = FileList['deployment_dir/**/*'].exclude('*.txt')
```

Then you can say on the cmd line:

```sh
rake clean
```

Read up the [tutorial](http://docs.rubyrake.org/tutorial).

Answer (score 1):

@adzdavies's answer is good, but assigning to `CLEAN` will produce the following warning since `CLEAN` is a constant:

```
warning: already initialized constant CLEAN
```

You should instead use `CLEAN`'s instance methods. It is a [Rake::FileList](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/Rake/FileList.html), so you can add something like this to your Rakefile:

```
require 'rake/clean'

# this is untested, but you get the idea
CLEAN.include('deployment_dir/**/*').exclude('*.txt')
```

Then run:

```
rake clean
```